# Integral $a_n=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{n\pi z}{4d}}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}dz.$

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I am currently working on finding a Fourier series representation for the electric potential following an array of electrically charged, coaxial rings along their central axis. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $R,d\in\mathbb{R}$, I was hoping to evaluate the following integral:
$$a_n=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{n\pi z}{4d}}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}dz.$$
If it helps, $R=1$ and $d=0.75$. Is this integral solvable, or would a numerical analysis be of better use? (I need to show that $a_n$ drops sufficiently fast as to allow an approximation including only the 2nd and maybe the 4th or 6th coefficient. Odd-$n$ will drop out later anyway.)

Thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: If $R=1$ then the denominator is $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ and then you would need to consider the branch cuts of  $\sqrt{1+z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: @808GroundState. $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ instead

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh heck

Comment: @808GroundState *"let the one who has never sinned throw the first stone"* I shall not be this one ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ha! Thank you kind Sir!

Comment: @808GroundState. If they gave me one cent every time I made things like that, I shouold be a millionaire ! Please, don' use *Sir*. I am already too old. Cheers

Comment: When you finish, add your answer to the post. If required, we could look at the asymptotics.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You got it Claude, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$I_n=\int\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi }{4d}z\right)}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}dz$$ Let $z=x R$ to make
$$I_n=\int\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n R}{4 d}x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\frac{\cos(kx)}{\sqrt{x^2+1} } dx=\Re\Big[\int\frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{x^2+1} } dx \Big]$$

Now, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).